# fixed length reader returns empty set. Weird issue

Tags: smooks

I have written a sample smooks config using fixed length reader[1] with many fields.
I see a weird issue here. That is, if i have the  last field AnnualReportReturnedDate[8] in the configuration it does not return any sets. that is my set is null. 
So, i checked one by one by adding all fields and my configuration works fine. When i try to add  AnnualReportReturnedDate[8] filed, it is not working.(taht is empty set is returned) Further if i change the length of that filed to 2/5 it works..but it is not working fro length 8. That is , 
if i defined `AnnualReportReturnedDate[2]--works`, `AnnualReportReturnedDate[8]--Not works`.

Why do i get this type of annoying issue?
[1]

```
<smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd"
    xmlns:fl="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/fixed-length-1.3.xsd">
    <fl:reader
        fields="RecordId[10]?trim,CompactedCorpName[60]?trim,FileNumber[9]?trim,CorporationName[60]?trim,...........,AnnualReportReturnedDate[8]?trim,AnnualReportReturnedCode[2]?trim"
        skipLines="1"></fl:reader>
</smooks-resource-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is, in my file, in the middle  it had a line, which did not have enough length of characters. SoO, smooks skipped the whole file to process.